# No-delay persist data between application restarts

Tags: c#, windows

I'm re-writing performance critical function in my application, and I need a good way to store record id.

Before that, I was storing the id to file, for that I had to lock file, write data and than flush it. This takes too long.

Are there any better ways to persist the record id?

Comment: Send a message to a queue and let it do the work?

Comment: Yep, queue is able to process ~2000msg per second, so if that is NOT fast enough, then there's a question if You need to search, sort data or NOT ? Do You need SQL for this ? do you need transaction support for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very unlikely that You would be bumping the HDD speed limit in this case.
But if You are - Your best option is to change the HDD to SSD, or even further - change it to a RAID SDD array - so that it would write in parallel.

If the problem is in Your c# code - 
well there are a couple of solutions (exploring write speeds)

[How to write super-fast file-streaming code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955911/how-to-write-super-fast-file-streaming-code-in-c)

[Performance of Writing to File C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437265/performance-of-writing-to-file-c-sharp)

Also - You may consider using `async/await`, to allow Your code to continue executing while the disk is processing Your Write request.